# Code signing in xcode fails when I add a static library to project

Tags: xcode, static, codesign

I created a Cocoa Touch static library that I want to add to a project I'm working on. The project built perfectly before I added the library but now it gives me a "codesign failed with exit code 1" error. Why would the library cause this and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure. Did you code sign the library? I have several static frameworks I've built and used without a problem. I haven't code signed them which is why I'm thinking you may have if it's possible.